# Disable Opentelemetry traces in NodeSDK

Tags: open-telemetry

Is there a way to disable Opentelemetry traces in NodeSDK.

I instantiated the NodeSDK instance using the code below

```
const sdk = new NodeSDK({
    metricReader: new PrometheusExporter(),
    instrumentations: [getNodeAutoInstrumentations()],
});
```

The metrics are registered and I can access them on port 9464.

The problem I am having is that all the request to the backend which I am logging started getting span metadata attached to them. [image: request with span metadata]

What I noticed is that when I specifically remove the instrumetation-http it will stop putting the metadata, but then I lose the metrics as well which I don't want.

```
const sdk = new NodeSDK({
    metricReader: new PrometheusExporter(),
    instrumentations: [getNodeAutoInstrumentations({ '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-http': { enabled: false } })],
});
```

My question is. Is there a way to disable tracing all together since I won't really be using it and don't need the extra overhead in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the environment variable `OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER` to `none`.

By default, it is set to `otlp`, [per the upstream docs](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/tree/main/experimental/packages/opentelemetry-sdk-node#exporters). This causes an OTLP exporter to be automatically configured. Setting the value to `none` should suppress this behavior.